# How do I solve the given three non-linear equations in three unknowns?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
\begin{align}
yz + 2xyz &= 0 \\
xz + x^2 z - 1 &= 0 \\
xy + x^2 y &= 0
\end{align}
$$
Solving these equations individually gives $y = z = 0$, and $x = -0.5$ from the first equation, $z = \frac{1}{x + x^2}$ from the second equation, and $x = y = 0$ or $x = -1$ from third equation. The final answer is given as
$$
\left( x, 0, \dfrac{1}{x + x^2} \right)
$$
for $x$ not equal to $0$ or $-1$. I don't understand how is this the final answer; especially why this system is satisfied for every $x$. How do we get to this final answer. If anyone could explain, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Solving these equations don't give you x=-0.5 nor z =0. Why do you think they do?  If y =0 the only equation with any singnifance is the second.  So you have only one equation with two unknowns.  That can't be solved.  We can only express one variable in terms of the other.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. Okay when ab=0 then **either** a=0 **or** b= 0. NOT BOTH. But you do not know which (yet). Equation 2) tells us neither x nor z are 0. So equation 3) tells us y is 0. Equation 1) is 0 (z+2xz)=0 and that tells use nothing. 3) is 0 (x+x^3)=0 so after we know y=0 it tells us nothing. Eq 2) is the only eq. that tells us anything. It tells us z (x+x^2)=1. So z=1/(x+x^2) is as far as we can go.

Answer (score 0):

1) $yz + 2xyz = 0 \implies yz(1+2x)=0 \implies $ either $y=0; z= 0;$ **OR** $x = 1/2$.

**BUT** we don't know which one of those is true.  We only know that at least *one* of them is true.

2) $xz + x^2z - 1 = 0\implies z(x + x^2) = 1$ so $z \ne 0$ and $x+x^2=x(1+x) \ne 0$ so $x \ne 0$ and $x \ne -1$ so $z = \frac{1}{x+x^2}$.

3)$xy + x^2y = 0\implies y*x(1+x) = 0$ so EITHER $y=0; x=0$ or $x=-1$.  But by equation 3) we know $x\ne 0$ and $x\ne -1$.  So that means $y= 0$

In Equation 1) we knew $y=0$ or $z= 0$ or $x = 1/2$.  But now we know $y=0$ so we have $0*z(1+2x) = 0$ which does not and *can* not tell us any more information.

In Equation 3) we know $y=0$ so $ 0*x(1+x) = 0$ and we *can't* know anything more.

In Equation 2) we know $x \ne 0$ and $x \ne = -1$ and $z=\frac{1}{x+x^2}$ and that's as far as we can go.  There is no more information to be had.

So the final answer is $x \ne 0,-1$ and $y = 0$ and $z=\frac{1}{x+x^2}$.  That's it.